# Billingsley convergence of probability measures - inequality used in Theorem 2

Tags: pr.probability, measure-theory, metric-spaces

On Page 8, Billingsley defines $f(x)=(1-\rho(x,F)/\epsilon)^{+}$ where $\rho(x,F)$ is the metric distance from the set $F$.  He then states $|f(x)-f(y)|\leq \rho(x,y)/\epsilon$ and goes on to use this in Theorem 1.2.  I have attempted to derive the inequality by considering the four cases $\rho(x,F)/\epsilon> 1$ and $\rho(y,F)/\epsilon> 1$, $\rho(x,F)/\epsilon\leq 1$ and $\rho(y,F)/\epsilon> 1$, $\rho(x,F)/\epsilon> 1$ and $\rho(y,F)/\epsilon\leq 1$, and $\rho(x,F)/\epsilon\leq 1$ and $\rho(y,F)/\epsilon\leq 1$ and considered $|f(x)-f(y)|$ for each of these.  I have used $\rho(x,y)\leq \rho(x,f)+\rho(y,f)$ for all $f\in F$ so $\rho(x,y)\leq \rho(x,F)+\rho(y,F)$.
However, I cannot make the inequalities work for me (beyond the first trivial case) and want to get on with the rest of the chapter.

I wondered whether anyone has come across this small problem and has a solution?

Comment: Note that $\rho(x, F) - \rho(y, F) \leq \sup_{z \in F} (\rho(x, z) - \rho(y, z)) \leq \rho(x, y)$.

Answer (score 0):

You can check that $|\rho(x,F)-\rho(y,F)|\le\rho(x,y)$ for all $x,y$ in the metric space. That is, $x\mapsto\rho(x,F)$ is Lipschitz continuous with Lipschitz constant $1$. Also notice that $\psi:u\mapsto (1-u/\epsilon)^+$ is Lipschitz continuous: $|\psi(u)-\psi(v)|\le|u-v|/\epsilon$. The composition $f(x)=\psi(\rho(x,F))$ is therefore Lischitz continuous with Lipschitz constant $1/\epsilon$.

Comment: Neat approach John thanks, much preferable to my bare knuckle attempt.